# Using javascript substring() to create a read more link

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I'm developing a Classic ASP page that pulls some content from a database and creates a Read more link after the first 100 characters as follows;

```
<div class="contentdetail"><%=StripHTML(rspropertyresults.Fields.Item("ContentDetails").Value)%></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var cutoff = 200;
        var text = $('div.contentdetail').text();
        var rest = $('div.contentdetail').text().substring(cutoff);
        if (text.length > 200) {
          var period = rest.indexOf('.');
          var space = rest.indexOf(' ');
          cutoff += Math.max(Math.min(period, space), 0);
        }

        var visibleText = $('div.contentdetail').text().substring(0, cutoff);

        $('div.contentdetail')
            .html(visibleText + ('<span>' + rest + '</span>'))
            .append('<a title="Read More" style="font-weight:bold;display: block; cursor: pointer;">Read More&hellip;</a>')
            .click(function() {
                $(this).find('span').toggle();
                $(this).find('a:last').hide();
            });

        $('div.contentdetail span').hide();
    });
</script>
```

However, the script obviously just cuts the text off after 100 characters. Preferably I would like it to keep on writing text until the first period or space, for example. Is this possible to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I got your question wrong, but you do know of the String.indexOf() function which returns the index of the first occurence of a certain substring (or -1 if the part was not found). Example: alert("foobar".indexOf("b")) alerts "3" as the index of "b". Maybe you can use this to truncate the string at the desired position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var cutoff = 100;
var text = $('div.contentdetail').text();
var rest = text.substring(cutoff);
if (text.length > cutoff) {
  var period = rest.indexOf('.');
  var space = rest.indexOf(' ');
  cutoff += Math.max(Math.min(period, space), 0);
}
// Assign the rest again, because we recalculated the cutoff
rest = text.substring(cutoff);
var visibleText = $('div.contentdetail').text().substring(0, cutoff);
```

**EDIT:** shortened it a bit.
**EDIT**: Fixed a bug
**EDIT**: QoL improvement

Comment: @moxn Thank you for the code. For some reason it isn't shortening the text or creating the Read more link. Perhaps my jQuery code is now not working with the code that you have provided? I'll edit the post to show the code I have now.

Comment: Thanks man. There's a strange little bug. My text first cuts off as follows; "Situated in the highly regarded area of Molescroft Beverley is this well presented detached family home" but then when I click on read more it seems to add some of the characters from the last word onto the end as follows; Situated in the highly regarded area of Molescroft Beverley is this well presented detached family homeome ..."

Comment: I fixed the bug. Of course the rest had to be extracted again with substring() after `cutoff` got adjusted. But probably bobince's solution is better performancewise...

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var text= $('div.contentdetail').text();
var match= text.match( /^(.{100}([^ .]{0,20}[ .])?)(.{20,})$/ );
if (match!==null) {
    var visibleText = match[1];
    var textToHide = match[3];
    ...do replacement...
}
```

The `{0,20}` will look forward for a space or period for up to 20 characters before giving up and breaking at exactly 100 characters. This stops an extremely long word from breaking out of the length limitation. The `{20,}` at the end stops a match being made when it would only hide a pointlessly small amount of content.

As for the replacement code, *don't* do this:

```
.html(visibleText + ('<span>' + textToHide + '</span>'))
```

This is inserting plain-text into an HTML context without any escaping. If `visibleText` or `textToHide` contains any `<` or `&` characters you will be mangling them, perhaps causing a XSS security problem in the process.

Instead create the set the `text()` of the div and the span separately, since that's the way you read the text in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly simple approach to getting endings at the word level, and shooting for *about* your given limit in characters.

```
var limit        = 100,
    text         = $('div.contentdetail').text().split(/\s+/),
    word,
    letter_count = 0,
    trunc        = '',
    i            = 0;

while (i < text.length && letter_count < limit) {
  word         = text[i++];
  trunc       += word+' ';
  letter_count = trunc.length-1;

}

trunc = $.trim(trunc)+'...';
console.log(trunc);
```