# Show and Hide Div for the text that comes dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem where we have to show/hide some text in the product description in the product detail page. The description has to be shortened upto desired number of lines and by clicking on "more" complete description is to be shown. I taken the following script from the link below:

> [Using javascript substring() to create a read more link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606336/using-javascript-substring-to-create-a-read-more-link)

And the code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var cutoff = 200;
        var text = $('div.contentdetail').text();
        var rest = $('div.contentdetail').text().substring(cutoff);
        if (text.length > 200) {
          var period = rest.indexOf('.');
          var space = rest.indexOf(' ');
          cutoff += Math.max(Math.min(period, space), 0);
        }  
        rest = text.substring(cutoff);  
        var visibleText = $('div.contentdetail').text().substring(0, cutoff);  
        $('div.contentdetail')  
            .html(visibleText + ('<span>' + rest + '</span>'))
            .append('<a title="Read More" style="font-weight:bold;display:block;cursor: pointer;">Read More&hellip;</a>')  
            .click(function() {  
                $(this).find('span').toggle();  
                $(this).find('a:last').hide();  
            });  
        $('div.contentdetail span').hide();  
    });  
</script>
```

But with the above script the entire description is converting into text format. But since the description contains unordered lists,header tags etc. it is not considering those. How to modify the above script to display the content as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use html() instead of text(). like this

```
var text = $('div.contentdetail').html();
var rest = $('div.contentdetail').html().substring(cutoff);
```

Rest is all correct. text() converts all html node data in pure text. html() preserves it. Give it a go, worked for me. In the previous link the problem was only for text. Since you have other elements like links and other stuff, you need to use html()

Comment: @Shades88-Thanx for your answer.i changed to html() in place of text() but when I assign cutoff to 900 characters the script is not considering and hiding the unordered lists

Comment: ohh you also have to replace text() to html() in this line `var visibleText = $('div.contentdetail').text().substring(0, cutoff);`. I forgot to mention that line but you could have figured that out. Also when you put cutoff to something greater that your text length your `rest` variable will be blank as substring is just unable to find index 900 in a text which contain less that 900 characters. So it would be better to check whether or not your `rest` variable is holding value. If it is blank then you should not proceed further and leave that text as it.

Comment: And if you found this useful, please mark this as an answer :)