# Expanding "read more" text

Tags: javascript, css, text, spry

I am trying to make this box so that when you click read more it gets larger and shows text below it.  Also would like to make a button that closes the text up again.

So far I tried the toggletext javascript command,
(found on: http://www.ehow.com/how_12006269_make-expandable-text-dreamweaver.html )
but it only puts text below the read more it doesnt affect the box below it, so all the sentences are running behind the next div element.

Also tried the spry collapsible panel in dreamweaver and it does the same thing, hides behind and doesn't move open again.

The other thing is that the expand function I made only can be customized once and if I copy it, the second one opens the text of the first one.

I need to make this easy to hand off to someone at the office who has no experience with web design to manage this part later.

I am a newbie designer, would really appreciate some help or new ideas how to do this. Thanks!!

Link:

http://gregorydesignbuild.net/projects/projectlist.php

Comment: This link has an example for creating readmore using jquery : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606336/using-javascript-substring-to-create-a-read-more-link

Comment: Just so you know... your website throws a boatload of JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 1):

I used the The Details disclosure element in HTML 5.

Just add a classical text box in WordPress then edit as HTML and add the following tags.

Into text

```xml
<details>
Summary text...
<summary>Read more</summary>
Detail text
</details>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Answer (score 0):

It's a styling thing. You have the `height` property declared on your `div.plistobtxtbox` that contains the read more buttons. If you remove that declaration in your *home.css* file the content beneath the read more content should be pushed down when the read more button is clicked.