# Cutting off a description if it's more than a set amount of words?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm curious, so I was on some sites specifically blogs. And I see their blog is like this:

```
CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE
```

but their description says something like

```
CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE CONTENT HERE
CONTENT HERE CONTENT...
```

I was wondering if I would have to use javascript or php to see if a `div` or `<p>` has too many words and cut it off accordingly?  I'm not sure of the terminology for this. Anyways, I tried setting max height of a div, and it cuts off the content, but I wanted it to add like a `...` or a `read more->` after the part that was cut off. Could someone provide insight on how someone could achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606336/using-javascript-substring-to-create-a-read-more-link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
theString = 'CONTENT HERE'; //can be dom element innerhtml/jQuery.html() as well
if(theString.length>100){
   theString = theString.substr(0,100)+'...';
   theString += '<div><a>Read More</a></div>'; //target area you need to place read more link
}
jQuery('.element').html(theString);
```

In this you replace everything after the amount to cut off with ...

If you want to also put the readmore in a seperate div/string you can target the new area with jquery pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, but it lacks Firefox support:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

More info here: http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis

Comment: Firefox has supported it since at least 14 major versions back, as long as you use it appropriately. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 1):

There's a jQuery plugin which allows to do just that. You can find it here: http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/

The overview from the website says the following:

> The Expander Plugin hides (collapses) a portion of an element's content and adds a "read more" link so that the text can be viewed by the user if he or she wishes. By default, the expanded content is followed by a "read less" link that the user can click to re-collapse it. Expanded content can also be re-collapsed after a specified period of time.

Through CSS, I know you can use `overflow: hidden`, `text-overflow: ellipsis` and `white-space: nowrap`, but I believe that only works if it's only one line, so I'd suggest the jQuery approach if it's longer texts.

Comment: All the other answers were great too, but I will make use of this Jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to trim your string, add `...` and then replace it into the html.
Modify or write a wrapper for adding the `...` as desired.

```
sDisplay = sFull.substr(0,50) + '...';
```