# Shortening long blocks of text based on words not characters to display a read more using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Objective

- Reduce long text to six words, with a "...show more"
- Way to collapse the text again after being expanded

### Summary

I want to cut the text to show a ".. read more" link that expands the content. This should cut off based on the number of words, not characters. I want to display only the first 6 words.

I also need to expand the collapse the text again by clicking a "show less" button.

### Current state

I have this working on my development site, but I had to cut to 36 which is an approximation to get to 6 words. I set up this [demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/RWjWWM)

### Previous research

I searched various similar questions but address how to collapse based on characters, not word count. For example, [Using javascript substring() to create a read more link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606336/using-javascript-substring-to-create-a-read-more-link)

And I read this but unclear as to how to integrate that back into my project: [javascript shorten string without cutting words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454235/javascript-shorten-string-without-cutting-words)

---

### Code

#### HTML

```
<p class="ticket-text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs shankle shoulder, chicken meatloaf andouille meatball. Filet mignon pork tenderloin prosciutto porchetta andouille, strip steak tri-tip biltong beef ribs shoulder doner t-bone alcatra kevin.</p>
```

### Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('.ticket-text').each(function(event){
        var max_length = 36;

        if($(this).html().length > max_length){

            var short_content   = $(this).html().substr(0,max_length);
            var long_content    = $(this).html().substr(max_length);

            $(this).html(short_content+
                    '<a href="#" class="read_more">...<br>[Read More]</a>'+
                    '<span class="more_text" style="display:none;">'+long_content+'</span>');

            $(this).find('a.read_more').click(function(event){ 
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).parents('.ticket-text').find('.more_text').show();
            }); 
        }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just split the words and do the show More when you have more than 6 words, and then change to Show Less so you can hide the long text again:

```js
$('.ticket-text').each(function(){
 var words = $(this).text().split(" ");
    var maxWords = 6;
    
    if(words.length > maxWords){
        html = words.slice(0,maxWords) +'<span class="more_text" style="display:none;"> '+words.slice(maxWords, words.length)+'</span>' + '<a href="#" class="read_more">...<br/>[Read More]</a>'
    
        $(this).html(html)
    
     $(this).find('a.read_more').click(function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass("less");
            event.preventDefault();
            if($(this).hasClass("less")){
             $(this).html("<br/>[Read Less]")
                $(this).parent().find(".more_text").show();
            }else{
             $(this).html("...<br/>[Read More]")
                $(this).parent().find(".more_text").hide();
            }
        })
    
    }
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="ticket-text">Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs shankle shoulder, chicken meatloaf andouille meatball. Filet mignon pork tenderloin prosciutto porchetta andouille, strip steak tri-tip biltong beef ribs shoulder doner t-bone alcatra kevin.</p>
<p class="ticket-text">short text</p>
```

To handle commas and dots, you could do something like this:

```
var words = $(this).text().replace(".").replace(",").split(" ").filter(function(a){return a});
```

This will replace all dots and commas for white spaces, then split by whitespaces, and then filter out the empty strings to keep only the words

Comment: This is helpful. The new challenge now is that the words now have a comma (sometimes 2) added after each word and no spacing between the words.

Comment: @JGallardo updated. You would need to do other stuff to keep the commans and dots on the text though

Comment: sorry this is new to me. I am curious where the commas are being generated from anyways. I am happy to have this cut down to six words, but the new problem of added commas and no spaces seem to add an problem. Your second line removes periods but I cant do that because it is a paragraph, so that would make it entirely unreadable.

Comment: @JGallardo yeah its a bit harder to do that. The example on jsfiddle works, although the text is not exactly replicated as in original, its understandable. You could make your own function to append words+space or the comma and dot without space instead of words.slice().join(" ") and it would look better

Comment: ok your example on jsfiddle works well. for some reason it is adding random spaces before a few commas and periods when I used this code on my page. But this is great, thank you.

Comment: @JGallardo no problem, here is a more manual version that keeps text without changing it: http://jsfiddle.net/sLaapxff/1/

Comment: @juvian your code is working great. thanks man.

Comment: @Monzur glad it keeps helping after all these years

Answer (score 0):

You can split the words according to max word count and have 2 string namely shortStr and longStr, then you can add read more in the html. This will also not generate any commas.

```
$('.ticket-text').each(function () {
  // var words = $(this).text().split(' ')
  var words = $(this)
    .text()
    .replace('.')
    .replace(',')
    .split(' ')
    .filter(function (a) {
      return a
    })
  var maxWords = 6
  var shortStr = words.slice(0, maxWords).join(' ')
  var longStr = words.slice(maxWords, words.length).join(' ')
  if (words.length > maxWords) {
    html =
      shortStr +
      '<span class="more_text" style="display:none;"> ' +
      longStr +
      '</span>' +
      '<a href="#" class="read_more">...<br/>[Read More]</a>'

    $(this).html(html)

    $(this)
      .find('a.read_more')
      .click(function (event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('less')
        event.preventDefault()
        if ($(this).hasClass('less')) {
          $(this).html('<br/>[Read Less]')
          $(this).parent().find('.more_text').show()
        } else {
          $(this).html('...<br/>[Read More]')
          $(this).parent().find('.more_text').hide()
        }
      })
  }
})
```